# Lpk.dll is missing, but can't login to fix the issue

Tags: windows-7, dll

My Great Aunt has just had a power cut (she uses a surge protector on her extension) and when she rebooted her PC it gave the error "lpk.dll is missing etc". However, to resolve the issue she has to have control of the PC. Here lies the issue, she cannot do anything on the PC. She gets to the lock screen and then it she has no control of the PC. She can't move the mouse, use the keyboard, use the touch screen. I was just curious, would the no control issue be a result of the missing dll, or is that a separate issue? I am quite the computer nerd and have never heard of this issue before, it's very odd.

Answer (score 1):

Since I just started to use windows 7 on my laptop, I don't know much... but I had a problem with the windows activation, so my windows crashed... and there was a way to fix it with the windows 7 installer (boot) dvd. I think that could be also useful to fix that "missing lpk.dll" problem:

- Just put in the dvd and reset the laptop, then boot from the dvd and instead of install/re-install windows 7 just repair it (for example: with the recovery/restoration to a previous working state of windows or something like that - this fixed my activation problem - or choose other option).
- Or use your good friend, called Google: https://www.google.hu/#q=lpk.dll+is+missing+windows+7+fix, because as I can see others had this problem too.

Cheers!